# Slow SQL execution when querying from view

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view, postgresql-performance

I execute `select *` from a **view** on 3 tables (`gis_wcdma_cells`, `wcdma_cells`, `wcdma_cells_statistic`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW gisview_wcdma_cell_statistic AS 
 SELECT gis_wcdma_cells.wcdma_cell_id,
    gis_wcdma_cells.geometry,
    wcdma_cells."Cellname",
    wcdma_cells."Longitude",
    wcdma_cells."Latitude",
    wcdma_cells."Orientation",
    wcdma_cell_statistic.avg_ecio,
    wcdma_cell_statistic.avg_rssi,
    wcdma_cell_statistic.message_count,
    wcdma_cell_statistic.measurement_count
 FROM gis_wcdma_cells,
    wcdma_cells
 LEFT JOIN wcdma_cell_statistic ON wcdma_cells.id = wcdma_cell_statistic.cell_id
 WHERE gis_wcdma_cells.wcdma_cell_id = wcdma_cells.id;
```

However, I find it's quite slow although I have created indexes for 3 tables in my view:

- hash index created in wcdma_cells.id
- wcdma_cell_statistic.cell_id
- gis_wcdma_cells.wcdma_cell_id

I find `select * from view` is much slower than select specific columns from the view. While SQL explanation  for `select *` looks faster (I mean the cost is much lower in `select *` case.). Could you help to explain why? And if there is any suggestion to make the query faster?

#### SQL explaination for "select *" from view

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..11501.93 rows=41036 width=479) (actual time=0.034..326.680 rows=41036 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=238761
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..9017.44 rows=41036 width=467) (actual time=0.026..183.752 rows=41036 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=125390
        ->  Seq Scan on gis_wcdma_cells  (cost=0.00..2690.36 rows=41036 width=396) (actual time=0.007..13.359 rows=41036 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=2280
        ->  Index Scan using wcdma_cells_id_idx on wcdma_cells  (cost=0.00..0.14 rows=1 width=71) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=41036)
              Index Cond: (id = gis_wcdma_cells.wcdma_cell_id)
              Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 0
              Buffers: shared hit=123110
  ->  Index Scan using wcdma_cell_statistic_cell_id_idx on wcdma_cell_statistic  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=41036)
        Index Cond: (wcdma_cells.id = cell_id)
        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 0
        Buffers: shared hit=113371
Total runtime: 334.551 ms
```

#### SQL explaination for select specific columns from my view

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2340.31..9007.59 rows=41036 width=58) (actual time=46.498..263.589 rows=41036 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=116667, temp read=400 written=394
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=2340.31..6523.10 rows=41036 width=58) (actual time=46.471..119.983 rows=41036 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (gis_wcdma_cells.wcdma_cell_id = wcdma_cells.id)
        Buffers: shared hit=3296, temp read=400 written=394
        ->  Seq Scan on gis_wcdma_cells  (cost=0.00..2690.36 rows=41036 width=4) (actual time=0.007..14.688 rows=41036 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=2280
        ->  Hash  (cost=1426.36..1426.36 rows=41036 width=54) (actual time=46.358..46.358 rows=41036 loops=1)
              Buckets: 2048  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 927kB
              Buffers: shared hit=1016, temp written=299
              ->  Seq Scan on wcdma_cells  (cost=0.00..1426.36 rows=41036 width=54) (actual time=0.004..24.612 rows=41036 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=1016
  ->  Index Scan using wcdma_cell_statistic_cell_id_idx on wcdma_cell_statistic  (cost=0.00..0.05 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=41036)
        Index Cond: (wcdma_cells.id = cell_id)
        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 0
        Buffers: shared hit=113371
Total runtime: 271.146 ms
```

I am running the SQL query in Navicat or PgAdmin tool. The query execution time is: *15 sec* for selecting specific column and *a few minutes* for `select *`.

Comment: Please, provide `CREATE …` statements for your view and involved tables. Also, update explanations to contain `EXPLAIN (analyze,buffers)` output instead.

Comment: That mixture of modern JOIN syntax and old-fashioned comma joins, along with all those extra brackets, make that query really hard to understand.

Comment: Update with more info..

Comment: `width=479` is different from `width=58` so fewer space is needed, allowing the optimiser to switch to a different  plan.

Comment: BTW: The final line from the query plans is missing (the one with the total time) BTW: the difference seems marginal : ~250ms vs ~350 ms Maybe the connnection with your frontend is the bottleneck?

Comment: Which `specific columns`? The actual query would go nicely with the question about performance - as well as table definitions and your version of Postgres.